# Linq query translation for Npoco: c# to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, npoco

What I am trying to do is: retrieving only certain fields from the model when querying a database with the NPoco ORM.

I am forced to do it in vb.net, and I want to use linq to make the code cleaner (instead of a hard-coded string, which would be my last resort).

I have found the linq query in c# [here](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/issues/52) (see @schotime [owner] first answer). So this is the linq query I want to translate:

```
db.FetchBy<User>(sql => sql.Select(x=> new { x.Id, x.Name }));
```

...which the Telerik c# to vb.net translator translates as:

```
db.FetchBy(Of User)(Function(sql) sql.[Select](Function(x) New From { x.Id, x.Name }))
```

This seems off (the `From` keyword gives an error) and none of the alternatives that I tried by myself have worked either.

Any ideas?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for ([anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx)):

```
db.FetchBy(Of User)(Function(sql) sql.Select(Function(x) New With {x.Id, x.Name}))
```

Comment: This was it. Works like a charm, thank you very much. Will accept the answer in 5min, don't know why but StackOverflow is forcing me to do so.